# multiple app packages for windows 10 should have same capabilities?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, package, windows-store

when uploading my uwp app packages to the store, if I want to have multiple packages lets say a package for each sdk and each device family seperately. 
e.g

**creators update :** Desktop package, mobile package, hololens, xbox.

**Fall creators update**: Desktop package, mobile package, hololens, xbox.

so for example my app wants to target latest 3 SDKs and 4 device families, so now I want to upload **4x3 = 7** app packages to the store.

Now my question is why do I need to have same capabilities and resources for all these packages? because the reason I have seperate packages for each device family and each sdk is because some of those packages will need **different capabilities** and also might have different resources, so can I have them different or do I need to have them exactly the same?

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements

Source Text :

If your app has more than one package, these app manifest elements must be the same in each package (**per targeted OS**):

- Package/Capabilities
- Package/Dependencies
- Package/Resources

> This **per targeted OS** confuses me, does it mean same capabilities etc for all windows 10 os versions? or can I have same resources for all device family packages on one windows 10 OS version? and have different resources for other OS ( sdk) version of windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare different capabilities in your separate package uploads - for different SDK versions, or device types.

I agree the doc is a bit confusing. I think it's referring to packages within an appxbundle (e.g. x86/x64/arm) that need to have the same capabilities. I'll get that section updated/clarified.

Comment: Thankyou Stefan for clarification I have also put the same question with these details on github repo of the docs as per new feedback system, you can track this issue over there if it helps :) here is the link to the issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/388